# My jquery script never executes, I believe it's an issue with the class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following script:

```
<script>
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").onclick = function () {
        alert("got in");
    };
</script>
```

and here's the code for my dropdown list

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin:5px;">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Choose Fix Version
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="fixVersionDropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The contents of the dropdown list are being built on the fly by another script, but I don't think that's the issue. If I use the inspector in Firefox, the "test" entry is listed as `.dropdown-menu > li > a`, which is the same as what I see if I inspect any of the dynamic entries. Additionally, when I select all `.dropdown-menu > li > a` entries, it highlights every item in the dropdown list.

So why doesn't clicking a `.dropdown-list > li > a` item not fire off the script?

Comment: When do you populate the dropdown dynamically? If the script that populates the drop down runs after your .onclick event handler addition, it's not going to do anything. "The contents of the dropdown list are being built on the fly by another script, but I don't think that's the issue." This is most certainly your issue.

Comment: It's just a script sitting at the bottom of the page, so I guess whenever the browser gets to it. I tried putting that in a `$( document ).ready()`, but it didn't seem to have an effect. Also, the test entry in the list doesn't work either, so I don't *think* that's the issue.

Comment: your script in your example needs to run after the drop down has been populated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1hL85usx/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait until the DOM is ready and your "onclick" should be just click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
            alert("got in");
     });
});
```

Comment: Damn. I tried the $(document).ready, and I tried changing the syntax, but not both. This worked. Thanks! I'll have to look into why this needs the document to be ready, though - I figured that since it doesn't run until a click is registered, it'd work just fine. Maybe it tries to attach listeners before there's anything to attach a listener to? Time to dive into the documentation I guess.

Comment: The "click" is only registering the event with the elements that are selected.   Until the DOM is fully loaded, the code wouldn't be able to attach to an element it can't find.  You are correct that this "fires" when the element is clicked, but the event registration is a different step in the process.   If you don't mind accepting the answer, it would be appreciated and will help others in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info! That makes sense. It sounds similar to what I kinda assumed was the process. Also yeah, sorry - there's a time limit on how quickly you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

simple incorrect syntax

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click( function() {
  alert("got in");
});

// -OR-

$(".dropdown-menu li a").on( "click", function() {
  alert("got in");
});
```

Comment: Simple enough that this still won't work with the document.ready? :)

Comment: i'm just correcting syntax here - but if you need to work with doc ready then wrap it in `$(function(){ //your stuff }`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click= function () {
     alert("got in");
  };
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what he has in his post.

Comment: The problem is not the assignment of the handler. It's the time when it will be assigned.

Comment: click() vs onclick()

Comment: The main problem is, that the handler is assigned before the elements exist.

Comment: @Tyr Glad someone here understands the problem.

Comment: Oh ok: http://api.jquery.com/on/ This delegates a click handler to present and future selections